# QiskitBackendNotFoundError: 'No backend matches the criteria'

Tags: ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I am struggling with the **QiskitBackendNotFoundError: 'No backend matches the criteria'** even though I am able to see the backends available to me.

```
  available_cloud_backends = provider.backends()
        print(available_cloud_backends)

[<IBMQSimulator('ibmq_qasm_simulator') from IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>, <IBMQSimulator('simulator_statevector') from IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>, <IBMQSimulator('simulator_mps') from IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>, <IBMQSimulator('simulator_extended_stabilizer') from IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>, <IBMQSimulator('simulator_stabilizer') from IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>, <IBMQBackend('ibm_brisbane') from IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>, <IBMQBackend('ibm_kyoto') from IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>, <IBMQBackend('ibm_osaka') from IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>]
```

When I am using the below code, it works:

```
# Execute the circuit using the simulator
simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
# simulator = Aer.get_backend('simulator_mps')
job = execute(circuit, backend=simulator, shots=65536)

#Get the result of the execution
result = job.result()

# Get the counts, the frequency of each answer
counts = result.get_counts(circuit)

# Display the results
plot_histogram(counts)
```

But, when I try to use, ibmq_qasm_simulator or simulator_statevector or simulator_mps or simulator_extended_stabilizer or simulator_stabilizer or ibm_brisbane or ibm_kyoto or ibm_osaka, I get the below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QiskitBackendNotFoundError                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[81], line 3
      1 # Execute the circuit using the simulator
      2 # simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
----> 3 simulator = Aer.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
      4 job = execute(circuit, backend=simulator, shots=65536)
      6 #Get the result of the execution

File ~/scratch/study_wong_hhl/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit_aer/aerprovider.py:64, in AerProvider.get_backend(self, name, **kwargs)
     63 def get_backend(self, name=None, **kwargs):
---> 64     return super().get_backend(name=name, **kwargs)

File ~/scratch/study_wong_hhl/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/providers/provider.py:55, in ProviderV1.get_backend(self, name, **kwargs)
     53     raise QiskitBackendNotFoundError("More than one backend matches the criteria")
     54 if not backends:
---> 55     raise QiskitBackendNotFoundError("No backend matches the criteria")
     57 return backends[0]

QiskitBackendNotFoundError: 'No backend matches the criteria'
```

Really not sure, what I am doing wrong? I think, there is something wrong with IBMQ systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems you are confusing IBM provider and Aer provider. They both provide backends, but not necessarily the same backends.

These are the backends for IBM provider

```python
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
service = QiskitRuntimeService(instance='ibm-q/open/main')

for backend in service.backends():
    print(backend.name)
```

```
simulator_statevector
simulator_stabilizer
ibm_brisbane
ibm_kyoto
ibm_osaka
ibmq_qasm_simulator
simulator_extended_stabilizer
simulator_mps
```

Some of them are simulators.

Aer is for local simulations, so they are all simulators.

```python
from qiskit_aer import Aer

for backend in Aer.backends():
    print(backend.name)
```

```
aer_simulator
qasm_simulator
statevector_simulator
unitary_simulator
```

Even when some of the might be semantically equivalent, the simulators provided by IBM provider do not have the same name as those provided by the Aer provider.

Comment: Thank you @luciano for great help.